# Fermat's (hypothetical) erroneous proof

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, math-history, big-list, fake-proofs

Until Wiles' proof of Fermat's last theorem all proposed proofs have been erroneous. It is not known which proof Fermat himself had in mind - but it is assumed that it was erroneous, too. Have there been proofs suggested as possibly Fermat's: which were in the mathematical style of Fermat, which contained errors that Fermat could have made, which could plausibly have been conceived by Fermat? Some historians of mathematics - Fermat experts of sorts - should be able to do so. Are there any such proposed proofs?

Comment: I think the most famous example of a proposed proof is the one by Lamé that made an understandable but unjustifiable assumption about unique factorisation. There is some information about this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem You will likely get much more relevant information if you post this on https://hsm.stackexchange.com (check for other relevant posts there first!).

Comment: I am no expert - but one should be able to prove FLT by assuming that the class number of $\Bbb Z[\zeta_p]$ is $1$, so that its ring of integers $\Bbb Z[\zeta_p]$ is a factorial ring (which is only true until $p=19$). Kummer found this mistake. Perhaps Fermat had this in mind.

Comment: It's impossible to say. But I suspect the classic proof (sometimes attributed to Kummer, or Lamé, or Cauchy) that works if you assume unique factorization just always exists would be a major contender. If not this, then perhaps Fermat thought every curve had genus at most $1$, and so thought that his descent arguments would generalize.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to History and Science of Mathematics.

Comment: According to [this HSM SE post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-evidence-is-there-that-fermat-had-a-proof-for-his-last-theorem) and [this MO post linked to it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33265/how-do-we-know-that-fermat-wrote-his-famous-note-in-1637/33289#33289), there is strong evidence of the fact that, if Fermat indeed wrote it, he himself eventually (and rather soon) realised that whatever he had been referring to was wrong, chiefly the fact that he seemingly never discussed it again.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: I think that the notion of class number was very out of Fermat's reach in his time and as I understand it, most opinions regarding his supposed proof maintain that he assumed, without being aware of it, that there was always unique factorization in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: The greatest work about a partial **non-erroneous** proof of FLT was made by Kummer, using what he called "regular primes". On the other hand Wiles's proof has been in fact "Wiles and Company proof (particularly important and decisive in the last step of search, was the job of Taylor, a young mathematician).

Comment: @Piquito Class number $1$ just means PID here for rings of integers. This is what Fermat knew, i.e., that it should be in particular a factorial ring (unique factorization). The use of "class number" is only for the readers of today, for better context.